# How to keep state of child BLOC depending on parent BLOC?

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I need an advice or magic kick in case how to one BLOC can work with other related BLOC.

I have this structure `building` -> `floors` -> `floorplan`. So I have three BLOCs

```dart
class BuildingBloc extends Bloc {
  // .. exposes state with lastSelectedBuildingId
}

class FloorBloc extends HydratebBloc {
  // ... exposes state with lastSelectedFloorId
  // ... refreshes (loads) floors for a specific building
  // ... manages current selection

  // Two ways to manage selected building
  // 1. Use class member `buildingId` and use it for getting floors
  // 2. Pass `buildingId` to `getFloors` method w/o passing it to constructor.
  FloorBloc(this.buildingId) : super(...)

  Future<BuildingFloor> getFloors([int? buildingId]) {
    ...
  }
}

class FloorPlanBloc extends HydratedBloc {
  // ... exposes state with scale and scrollOffset
  // ... allows to zoom image and scroll it.
}
```

When `lastSelectedBuildingId` of `BuildingBloc` is changed the GUI shows a tree with building's floors. When `lastSelectedFloorId` of `FloorBloc` is changed the GUI shows an image with a floor plan. This image can be scaled and scrolled.

I need to save current floor selection and scale/scrollOffset of selected image plan when I go out from the page of buildings and restore it when I return back (that is why I use `HyndratedBloc`). But when building is changed (new one is selected) I need to reset all previous state for `FloorPlanBloc`. So I need to implement "negotiation" between `FloorBloc` and `FloorPlanBloc`. Should `FloorBloc` creates and returns `FloorPlanBloc`? Or should `FloorBloc` keeps the state for `FloorPlanBloc` and then pass it to `FloorPlanBloc` on create? I am little lost so maybe someone gives me any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can `dependency inject` `Bloc`s one into another and listen to its events. Something like this:

```
class BuildingBloc extends Bloc {
  BuildingBloc(super.initialState);
  // .. exposes state with lastSelectedBuildingId
}

class FloorBloc extends Bloc {
  final BuildingBloc buildingBloc;
  FloorBloc(this.buildingBloc, super.initialState) {
    // listening on BuildingBloc events
    buildingBloc.stream.listen((event) {
      // reacting to some event from BuildingBloc
      if (event is BuildingBlocEvent) {
        // ... do something
        getFloors(event.buildingId); // e.g.
      }
    });
  }

  Future<BuildingFloor> getFloors([int? buildingId]) async {
    // ...
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    return BuildingFloor();
  }
}

class FloorPlanBloc extends Bloc {
  final FloorBloc floorBloc;
  // inject FloorBloc
  FloorPlanBloc(this.floorBloc, super.initialState) {
    // listening on FloorBloc events
    floorBloc.stream.listen((event) {
      // reacting to some event from FloorBloc
      if (event is FloorBlocEvent) {
        // ... do something
      }
    });
  }
}
```

So you will inject them with `BlocProvider` or `MultiBlocProvider` like so:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (ctx) => BuildingBloc(BuildingBlocInitialState()),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (ctx) => FloorBloc(ctx.read<BuildingBloc>(), FloorBlocInitialState()),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (ctx) => FloorPlanBloc(ctx.read<FloorBloc>(), FloorPlanBlocInitialState()),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(home: HomePage()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The listen callback expects a state and not an event. So, it is to check what state has been emitted and then trigger/add your own custom event. This event can then be handled as usual by the bloc.